# Dijkstra's algorithm on a reverse graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, dijkstra

If we reverse a graph G to G' and run Dijkstra's algorithm on G' from a source vertex 't', will this algorithm give shortest path from all vertices to 't' in G. Can someone prove or find counter example?

Comment: It will give the shortest paths **from** t in G'. But those are indeed equivalent to the shortest paths to t in G, if that's what you mean. Given that such shortest paths exist of coure, i.e. no negative cycle, and vertices are connected.

Comment: Proof by contradiction seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: YES, your statement is correct in a DIRECTED Graph**

In an undirected graph `G`, the reversal, `G'` would produce the same graph `G`, and thus, when you find the shortest distance from source vertex `s` to all other vertices, you are automatically finding the shortest path from all vertices to `s` since the graph can be traversed in reverse direction (undirected).

In a directed graph, when you find shortest path from `s` (source) to all other vertices (destinations), you are travelling in a single direction, from `source` `--->` `destination_1`, from `source` `--->` `destination_2`, from `source` `--->` `destination_3` ...

So, if you reversed all directions in the graph, all your shortest paths will be: to `source` `<---` `destination_1`, to `source` `<---` `destination_2`, to `source` `<---` `destination_3` ... and note that **These paths will NOT be the same as before** i.e. when you run `Dijkstras` on `G'`, the algorithm thinks it is finding shortest path from `s` to all `d`'s, whereas in reality, since you reversed the directions, the shortest path arrows are actually pointing in reverse direction giving us shortest path from all `d`'s to `s` and NOT from `s` to `d`'s.

```
Graph G:  

       7           +++++  
   //===>===>====>/ D2 /  
  //              +++++  
 //   /--<<---<--/   /|\
s <---         2      | 1 
 \\   \__<<___        |
  \\      9    \      |
   \\           \ +++++  
    \\===>=====>/ D1 /  
          10    +++++  


Graph G':

       7           +++++
   /----<----<---</ D2 /
  /               +++++
 /    //==>>====>==/   ||
s >===       2         || 1
 \    \__>>___         || 
  \      9    \       \||/
   \           \ +++++
    \---<------</ D1 /
          1     +++++
```

As you can see above, in G, shortest paths from `s` to `d1` is `s -> d1` and from `s` to `d2` is `s -> d2` (shown in double lines (`=`, `\\`, `//`)).

Upon reversing the directions, but NOT the weights (obviously), we see that the shortest paths from `s` to `d1` is `s -> d2 -> d1` and from `s` to `d2` is `s -> d2` which is the output of `Djikstras` algorithm.

If you were to now set the direction to what it was originally, clearly all the chosen paths are actually the shortest paths **TO** `s` and NOT from `s`.

```
Graph G:

       7           +++++
   /---->---->--->/ D2 /
  /               +++++
 /    //==<<===<==/   /||\
s <===       2         || 1
 \    \__<<___         || 
  \      9    \        ||
   \           \ +++++
    \--->------>/ D1 /
          1     +++++
```

P.S.: I know that the presentation isn't that great. sorry 'bout it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if G is an undirected graph. It would make no difference for the shortest path on the reverse graph.

Second of all, if G is a directed graph and if we take a closer look of Dijkstra’s, it only states choosing shortest edges among neighbors. So i guess it will work too.